# JavaScript to join text with a delimiter from each line in an unordered list and append to another ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I need text pulled from named spans in an unordered list to be joined and appended to another ul. My code will join all the words, but I'm unable to determine how to join the words in each individual line with a '|' separating each of the words in that line.

For example, here is my original unordered list:

```
<ul id="addTERM-viewable">
<li id="NEWterm-0"><span class="termTXT" name="combine" id="term-0">word one</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-0-alt-0">123</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-0-alt-1">456</span></li>
<li id="NEWterm-1"><span class="termTXT" name="combine" id="term-1">word two</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-1-alt-1">678</span></li>
<li id="NEWterm-2"><span class="termTXT" name="combine" id="term-2">word three</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-2-alt-1">900</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-2-alt-2">321</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#moveToPointsTips').on("click", function() {   
    
   var textArray =  $("ul#addTERM-viewable li").each(function(i, el){
               $(el).attr('id', 'NEWterm-' + ($(el).index()));
        }); 

        var vals = textArray.map(function () {
            var value =  $(this).find('span[name="combine"]').text();
            return value;
            value.forEach(function(words){
            words.join('|');
            });
        }).get();

        vals.forEach(function(t){
        $('#patterns').append('<li>' + t + '</li>');
        });
})
});
```

And here's the resulting second unordered list ("#patterns"):

```
<ul id="patterns">
<li>word one123456</li>
<li>word two678</li>
<li>word three900321</li>
</ul>
```

However, what I'm seeking is this:

```
<ul id="patterns">
<li>word one|123|456</li>
<li>word two|678</li>
<li>word three|900|321</li>
</ul>
```

I know it must be something relatively simple but I'm at a loss. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
 var value =  $(this).find('span[name="combine"]').text();
```

to:

```
var value =  $(this).find('span[name="combine"]').map((idx, ele) => ele.textContent).get().join('|');
```

For each span get the text only and return an array (refer. [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)), join the resulting array

The snippet:

```js
$('#moveToPointsTips').on("click", function() {
    var textArray =  $("ul#addTERM-viewable li").each(function(i, el){
        $(el).attr('id', 'NEWterm-' + ($(el).index()));
    });
    var vals = textArray.map(function () {
        var value =  $(this).find('span[name="combine"]').map((idx, ele) => ele.textContent).get().join('|');
        return value;
    }).get();

    vals.forEach(function(t){
        $('#patterns').append('<li>' + t + '</li>');
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="moveToPointsTips">moveToPointsTips</button>
<ul id="addTERM-viewable">
    <li id="NEWterm-0"><span class="termTXT" name="combine" id="term-0">word one</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-0-alt-0">123</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-0-alt-1">456</span></li>
    <li id="NEWterm-1"><span class="termTXT" name="combine" id="term-1">word two</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-1-alt-1">678</span></li>
    <li id="NEWterm-2"><span class="termTXT" name="combine" id="term-2">word three</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-2-alt-1">900</span><span class="altermTXT" name="combine" id="term-2-alt-2">321</span></li>
</ul>

<ul id="patterns">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone'll have a method using map instead, but here's a quick few loops to do what you want:

```
$('#moveToPointsTips').on("click", function() {
  //array for new list items
  var items = [];
  $('#addTERM-viewable li').each(function() {
    //for each list item, we'll create a new array to hold all span texts
    var thisItem = [];
    $(this).find("span").each(function() {
      thisItem.push($(this).text());
    });
    //join the span texts with your delimiter
    items.push(thisItem.join('|'));
  });
    
  //our new unordered list
  var newList = $('<ul>');
  $.each(items, function(k, v) {
    //for each of the previous items, whose spans' content we joined, add them to the new unordered list
    newList.append($('<li>').append(v));
  });
  //just so we can verify it looks like we want
  console.log(newList[0].outerHTML);
  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ysoqh1u/

Comment: I appreciate your solution and annotations/notes. This will actually help me with another project.